# One signal - How to retrieve the sent data from notification object?

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

I have integrated OneSignal into my Ionic app (Ionic + StencilJS + vanilla JavaScript) following this guide: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup.

In my app, upon clicking the notification, it is stored on the device by retrieving the relevant data from the notification object in my use case. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to retrieve the date.

This is the object retrieved upon opening the app.

```
{
    "action": {
        "type": 0
    },
    "notification": {
        "androidNotificationId": 1715699538,
        "groupedNotifications": [],
        "notificationId": "a7322c7e-80da-4406-8354-049c346417e8",
        "templateName": "",
        "templateId": "",
        "title": "title",
        "body": "body",
        "lockScreenVisibility": 1,
        "fromProjectNumber": "866050520933",
        "priority": 5,
        "additionalData": {
            ....
        },
        "rawPayload": "{\"google.delivered_priority\":\"normal\",\"google.sent_time\":1689242144132,\"google.ttl\":259200,\"google.original_priority\":\"normal\",\"custom\":\"{\\\"a\\\":{\\\"notification_url\\\":\\\"\\\\\\/news\\\\\\/2\\\"},\\\"i\\\":\\\"a7322c7e-80da-4406-8354-049c346417e8\\\"}\",\"pri\":\"5\",\"vis\":\"1\",\"from\":\"866050520933\",\"alert\":\"body.\",\"title\":\"title\",\"google.message_id\":\"0:1689242144148610%e0ad9d53f9fd7ecd\",\"google.c.sender.id\":\"866050520933\",\"androidNotificationId\":1715699538}"
    }
}
```

I assume that if you're on an Android app, you need to retrieve the date by converting the timestamp from google.sent_time. But what about iOS? Since I don't have a way to directly test the app on iOS yet, I wanted to understand what the structure would be in that case, so I know how to map the data.

It seems to me that the date cannot be retrieved from anywhere else, right? I haven't found any information in either the documentation or the OneSignal sending dashboard.

Thanks